# Covariant Derivative of Contravariant component

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensors, vector-fields

I was reading about the **Voss-Weyl** formula for the computation of Divergence of vector in curvilinear coordinate system. From my understanding the Divergence is equivalent to covariant derivative of contravariant components of vector, so can I replace the covariant derivative of contravariant components of a vector everytime with Voss-Weyl formula?

$$\boldsymbol\nabla \cdot F=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\vert g \vert}} \partial_i\left(\sqrt{\vert g \vert}F^i\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it is the same divergence of a contravariant tensorfield. The V-W formula calculates it in a nontensor way without Christoffel symbols.
(Pavel Grinfeld: Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces,
 p. 144-145)

Comment: I might add that the Voss-Weyl formula for $\nabla_\mu X^\mu$ works only if $X^\mu$ are the components of the vector field $X$ _in a coordinate basis $\{\partial_\mu\}$_, that is $X = X^\mu \partial_\mu$. In a more general basis $\{e_\mu\}$, the symbol $\partial_\mu$ doesn't make sense, so the formula cannot be applied.